# Creating .o file with make

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to learn how to write makefiles. I have started reading the manual of gnu make: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html#Simple-Makefile

I have 3 files in the same directory:

- main.cpp: which creates a rectangle and prints some information. Therefor it includes Rectangle.h
- Rectangle.h: header file for rectangle class
- Rectangle.cpp: implementation of rectangle class

I am having troubles with the include of Rectangle.h in main.cpp. My makefile is:

```
main: main.o rectangle.o
    g++ -o main.exe main.o rectangle.o

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp
rectangle.o: Rectangle.cpp
    g++ Rectangle.cpp
clean:
    rm main.exe main.o rectangle.o
```

I know something is missing to create main.o but I can't find out what it is. I tried adding various variations of Rectangle.h/.o/.cpp and finding something on the internet but I was unable to find something.

Help will be much appreciated :)

PS: The code is fine, I can compile it with the command:

g++ -o main.exe main.cpp Rectangle.cpp

Comment: g++ main.cpp -c -o main.o

Comment: Use the `-c` option with the compiler to produce an object file rather than trying to link an executable.  That's what Neil said, but explained a bit.  Also note that `make` knows how to create a `.o` file from a `.cpp` (or `.c`) file without you telling it.  You could simply remove the rules listing the `.o` files.  Or keep them but list `Rectangle.h` on the RHS of the colon to indicate that if the header changes, the object file needs to be rebuilt.  But remove the compilation rule; `make` will provide that anyway.  Also, your rule for `main` creates `main.exe`, not `main`. Fix that too.

Comment: Just to be very clear: this issue has nothing whatever to do with make or makefiles.  The problem is that the compiler invocation you put into your makefile is wrong.  You need to read the documentation on your compiler to learn about how to invoke it to get the results that you need.  Make is not a compiler: it's a tool used to run any type of program that can update files.  One type of program you _could_ use with make is a compiler, but it's up to you to know how to properly run the program.  Make does have built-in rules that do work correctly, if you wanted to use those instead.

Answer (score 3):

man g++

> When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking. The "overall options" allow you to stop this process at an intermediate stage. For example, the -c option says not to run the linker. Then the output consists of object files output by the assembler.

Comment: Can you or anyone recommend a book or a website where the writing of makefiles is explained step by step, possibly with code examples?

Comment: You could read the GNU manual on make: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html .